# FCC/ETSI conformance with backscatter

Tags: rfid, fcc, emissions

Do **passive backscatter** devices fall under regulations of FCC/ETSI?

Suppose a system emits a 4W EIRP tone in the ISM band (conforming to FCC/ETSI regulations). A fully passive device backscatters data not only on its fundamental but also **on its harmonics**.

- Is this passive backscatter "emission" on the harmonics regulated by FCC/ETSI?
- If a complete system were to be certified, would that only check if the transmitter satisfies the standards or would it also take into account if passive tags backscatter at different frequencies?

The information I found is unfortunately fairly vague.
For FCC, I found https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/ea/presentations/files/may05/New_Policies_Pt._15_SD.pdf which states that passive tags do not have to be tested individually and since its emissions are much lower than that of the reader, only the reader has to be tested. However, this is vague and is not an official document.

For ETSI, I found [Draft ETSI
EN 302 208](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/302200_302299/302208/03.01.00_20/en_302208v030100a.pdf), which states fairly clear limits in section 4.5.2.3. However, it is unclear if this applies to active tags or also passive tags.

Comment: ETSI is not a regulator. It's a standardization body.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, all emitters fall under the rules of the local regulatory body (which seems to be FCC in your case), unless there's a specific norm that exempts them (which seems to be the case in the US for tags, if you're reading that policy right).

ETSI is not a regulatory body, but a standardization organization, so they have nothing to do with this; the document you're linking to is a *recommendation* on how to technically implement the respective EU directive (and it's up to the EU member state to convert that directive into law; they *can*, but don't *have to* refer to an ETSI standard in the laws they formulate).

So, you'd need to read that EU directive, [Directive 2014/53/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/GA/TXT/?uri=celex:32014L0053), and then check whether and how the individual member states implement that directive.

Again, the ETSI doesn't have any powers here, they just propose a technical standard.

Comment: ETSI is related to EU regulation (European Commission), whereas the FCC is the US regulatory body so has nothing to do with EU standards.

Comment: The linked document (the directive) does not contain any technical values. From that document it is unclear where to look further for the required values.

Comment: @HorrorVacui as said, it's a [*EU directive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(European_Union)), which leaves implementation of that into law up to the member states. You'll need to read the spectrum regulation law of the EU member you're interested in.